# Different values on encryption using the same container

Tags: c#, encryption, key, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have 2 Projects in the same solution, in one project I encrypt a message using `SignData` and in the other project I am recreating the message that was encrypted in the first project and I compare the results to see if they are the same. But the encryption from the first project doesn't return the same value like the encryption from the second project. How can I make so that if i give the same byte array in both the projects I get the same value returned. I think that `RSA` generates 2 different keys but I use the same container

```
param.KeyContainerName = "SignatureContainer101";
```

Is there any way that I can do this without passing any Key? I need it to run locally on the same machine. Or any other suggestions in what I can do to get the same result?
This is the code I am using:

```
public static byte[] SignData(byte[] message)
    {

        //convert data to be signed in a byte array
        byte[] byteSignature2;

        CspParameters param = new CspParameters();
        //Giving container a name, so we can use the same keys for verifying data.
        param.KeyContainerName = "SignatureContainer101";

        //Initializing RSACryptoServiceProvider
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(param))
        {
            //We want RSACryptoServiceProvider to save keys in keystore
            //because we want to keep signature generation routine seperate
            //from verifying data against signature.
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
            byte[] byteSignature = rsa.SignData(message, "SHA256");
            byteSignature2 = new byte[byteSignature.Length];
            byteSignature2 = byteSignature;



        }
        return byteSignature2;
    }
    public static bool VerifyData(byte[] originalMessage, byte[] signedMessage)
    {

        bool isSuccess = false;

        CspParameters param = new CspParameters();
        //Utilizing the same key container which was created during
        //signature generation process i.e. in GetDataSignature(string data) function.
        //If we don't utilize the same keycontainer, VerifyData will always return false
        //because RSACryptoSeriveProvider initialization will generate new keys.
        param.KeyContainerName = "SignatureContainer101";

        //Initializing RSACryptoServiceProvider
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(param))
        {

            //verifying data against signature
            isSuccess = rsa.VerifyData(originalMessage, "SHA256", signedMessage);
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is the problem, exactly.

> How can I make so that if i give the same byte array in both the projects I get the same value returned.

Do you expect `SignData` to return *exactly* the same bytes when called twice on an identical message with an identical key? It won’t and it *shouldn’t*. Every time an “identical” asymmetric (public-key) encryption/signing is done, it should have a *different result*. That is achieved using a random piece of padding used in the process. It is needed because in public-key cryptography, one of the keys is *public*, and if no randomness was used, it would make the cryptographic properties weaker. (For more information, see e.g. [this answer on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33754/2530).)

So, you should not compare the result byte-by-byte, you should use the `VerifyData` method to check whether the signature is *correct*, not whether it is *identical*.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, I get the signature from the first project and compare it with the recreated message that was used for signing, but the verification fails...

Comment: Do you run the verification under the same user account (on the same machine) as the user account which was used to sign the message?

Answer (score 0):

I found no problem in you code. It works! This is what I've done:

```
public partial class Program
{
    protected override void Execute()
    {
        var message1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello there,");
        var message2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello there");
        var signed = SignData(message1);
        var notOK = VerifyData(message2, signed);
        var oK = VerifyData(message1, signed);
    }

    public static byte[] SignData(byte[] message)
    {
        byte[] byteSignature2;

        var param = new CspParameters
                    {
                        KeyContainerName = "SignatureContainer101"
                    };
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(param))
        {
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
            var byteSignature = rsa.SignData(message, "SHA256");
            byteSignature2 = byteSignature;
        }
        return byteSignature2;
    }
    public static bool VerifyData(byte[] originalMessage, byte[] signedMessage)
    {
        bool isSuccess;

        var param = new CspParameters
                    {
                        KeyContainerName = "SignatureContainer101"
                    };
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(param))
            isSuccess = rsa.VerifyData(originalMessage, "SHA256", signedMessage);
        return isSuccess;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works when i verify the data in the same project but when i verify it in another project it doesn't work, it returns false